# Python - Adding a string in a data from a list

Tags: python

I'm currently stuck in this right now.

I have a code right here:

```
words = ["Hello","how","are","you"]
arrlen = len(words)
val1, val2, val3, val4 = words
```

What I want to do is add `".mp4"` in each `val1`, `val2`, `val3` and `val4`. Is there any way to achieve this? I have tried `val1 + ".mp4"`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
>>> words = ["Hello","how","are","you"]
>>> words = [x + ".mp4" for x in words]
>>> words
['Hello.mp4', 'how.mp4', 'are.mp4', 'you.mp4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutate each item along with the unpacking:

```
words = ["Hello","how","are","you"]
arrlen = len(words)
val1, val2, val3, val4 = ["{}.mp4".format(word) for word in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function.

Directly from the docs:

> Returns an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results.

Here the function is a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) instead and *maps* each element from `words` with `+ '.mp4'`, which is exactly what you want:

```
words = ['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
words = list(map(lambda s: s + '.mp4', words))
print(words)
```